# Spinner 2 data not populating properly

Tags: android

I am trying to load spinner2 data based on spinner1 item selection. My spinner1 loads without any issues. I have got two categories in spinner1. Before selecting any value on spinner1, my spinner2 is loaded with second categories values.

EDIT:
One thing i realized now. i have got 2 values in spinner1(category). when nothing is selected in spinner1 , spinner2 is loaded with item2's values. if i select item1 in spinner1, it loads properly. If i select item2 in spinner1 nothing is populated in spinner2. Because of my hint addition there is some issue i think.

minimal spinner2 part in MainActivity

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                            getSpinner2(id);
}

        private void getSpinner2(Long id) {

        MyRestClient.getForSpinner2(MainActivity.this, "MyRestService/product/"+id, 
            headers.toArray(new Header[headers.size()]), null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

       @Override
       public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {

       ArrayList<String> spinnerArray2 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
       final SpinnerAdapter2 spinnerAdapter2 = new SpinnerAdapter2(MainActivity.this, spinnerArray2);   

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) { 
            try {
                            JSONObject c = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            String  productArray = c.getString("product");
                            spinnerAdapter2.add(productArray);
                            } 
                            catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

        spinnerAdapter2.add("Select One");  
        spinner2.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter2);
        spinner2.setSelection(spinnerAdapter2.getCount());
        spinnerAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    }
```

and i have got this to show hint on spinneradapter2 class

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        int count = super.getCount();
        return count > 0 ? count - 1 : count;
    }

.
.
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
.
.
if (position == getCount()) {

        viewHolder.product.setText("");
        viewHolder.product.setHint(products);
    } else {
    viewHolder.product.setText(products);
    }
  }
```

Comment: put your screen shot for what you want actually

Comment: share the code for first spinner on itemselected

Comment: where you calling this method?getSpinner2(Long id) {

Comment: I want to populate spinner2 based on the item i select on spinner 1. I will try to add screenshot now.

Comment: @naruto i calling from onitemselected of spinner1 method

Comment: @Hala.m please check i have added the part

Comment: why using  getSpinner2(id); not  getSpinner2(position);

Comment: @Hala.m even then same result

Answer (score 0):

Please try `spinnerAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();` after adding all elements to your adapter. Maybe it will help. And I thik you should add this items to spinnerArray2 and then create adapter using this object.

Comment: It didnt help. its loading second item in second category

Comment: @matejko219 Next time don't add this(suggestion) into answer, add it to comment.

Comment: @DevMike when I was writing this answer I haven't got +50 reputaion so I could not comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Put  `spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);` inside spinner1 setOnItemSelectedListner.

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

   parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

   spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);

   Log.e("Position", ""+position); 

 if(position > 0){ 

 getSpinner2(position); 

 } else { 

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Spinner oth postion is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

 }     
}
```

Comment: I can't add this method. It says the method is not applicable for the arguments Mainactivity. One thing i realized now. i have got 2 values in spinner1(category). when nothing is selected in spinner1 , spinner2 is loaded with category2's values. if i select item1 in spinner1, it loads properly. If i select item2 in spinner1 nothing is populated in spinner2. Because of my hint addition there is some issue i think. please check that.

Comment: are you there? can i come in discussion?

Comment: @user3785322 yes sure

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that onitemselected will be called first time without user actions and since you are adding a hint you should check that position is larger than 0 which is the hint position if there is no hint then skip the check of zero position

so your new selection will be like

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                      if(position>0){
                        parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        getSpinner2(position);
                      }
                  }
```

also

```
spinnerAdapter2.add("Select One");
```

call this before adding other values to the adapter to make sure it is in first location

Comment: Yes i am adding spinnerAdapter2.add("Select One"); at first.  can u come on discussion?

Comment: sure I don't know how though

Comment: I too dont know

Comment: "MyRestService/product/"+id is the id 0,1,2 ?
or is it custom ids?

Comment: Yes it is 0,1,2.  Now without selecting anything in spinner1, spinner 2 shows item2's values. then both spinner1 items selection shows item1 values in spinner2.

Comment: did you add the if(pos>0)? if so also update  getSpinner2(position); to  getSpinner2(position-1); id you still have issue tell me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122851/discussion-between-hala-m-and-user3785322).